# Nuxt env после build

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, .env

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как после генерации SPA Nuxt проекта (build) оставлять в нем конфиг (env или другой)?

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понимаю, то вам поможет https://github.com/nuxt-community/dotenv-module

[Тут](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-env/) описано как работать с переменными в самом приложении.